# Laravel 5 - Define custom route method?

Tags: laravel-5, routes, custom-routes

I just got an issue , i have 2 problems :

1. I want create a custom route for fast using without copy past code many time. Example Laravel 5 have default Route:resource (...) to make Restful! But i want to make my custom route function , Route:api(...) , Route:xxx(...) ... and I can custom it what I want !
2. How can I use multi route file ? Example : I can define route in App\User\route.user.php , App\Book\route.book.php .... because now, I can only use route file in route folder default !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not understand properly question 1. But for question 2, try this:

Go to `app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php`. Look for the function `mapWebRoutes()`. The line

```
require base_path('routes/web.php');
```

Duplicate it and change so you now have :

```
require base_path('routes/web.php');
require base_path('app/User/route.user.php');
require base_path('app/Whatever/route.whatever.php');
```

And laravel will load all routes within those files. Now, I've tested this, it works (Laravel 5.3) but I can't guarantee anything or if there are going to be conflicts with routes (duplicates). But yeah, it works.

Comment: yeah, thank Eddy, finally I found solution for question 2! Question 1 I want to make a new static function for Route , example Route::myfunction() . and in myFunction() I can define with GET method will map to Controller@func1 , with POST will map to Controller@func2 , with PUT method will map to Controller@func3 ...